# Track down why window.open does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Other attempts to use `window.open('url', '_blank')` within this script work as desired. This one, not opening a new tab, uses different logic following a `confirm()` prompt. The logic is to display a portion of the page if 'Reserved' is found in it or to redirect to the target page otherwise.

The redirect is automatic as a result of the `$.ajax` success handler. Neither method of redirect makes any changes.

form for 2nd method:

```
<form method=\"get\" id=\"formgoregistry\" name=\"goregistry\" action=\"\" target=\"_blank\">
</form>
```

javascript function in question:

```
function getRegistryInfo(num) {
    // for 2nd method, set the form's action
    $('#formgoregistry').attr('action', 'http://somesite.com/somefile?n=somevalue');

    var response = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'purchases_registry.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { number: num },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('response = '+data);
            if (data.indexOf('Reserved') > 0) {
                //  work with the result
                //  Code in here works fine
                ....
            }
            else {
                // wrong data, redirect to outside page
                //  **  Neither of these method open a new tab
                // 1st method
                var url = 'http://somesite.com/somefile?n=somevalue';
                console.log('url = '+url);                // prints the correct url
                var w = window.open(url, '_blank');       // NO new tab or error
                console.log('window = '+w);               // window = undefined

                // 2nd method (setting form's action beforehand)
                console.log(document.goregistry.action);  // prints the correct url
                document.goregistry.submit();             // NO new tab or error
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am wondering if the window being undefined is part of the problem and why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to open the link in new window :

```
echo "<form action=\"your_link.php?id=\" method=\"post\" target=\"myWindow\", onsubmit=\"window.open('', this.target, 'width=300,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');return true;\">
```

or in HTML language :

```
<form action="your_link.php?idk=$id=" method="post" target="myWindow", onsubmit="window.open('', this.target, 'width=300,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');return true;">
```

If you using a href method just simply change onsubmit to onclick, that's all I know, hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: The submit need to be in javascript. `window.open('url');` or  `document.goregistry.submit();`